# How to Link PHP Sub Categories(Pages) Dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I have There PHP File getting Data From MySQL Database called:

**clubs.php

club.php

player.php**

the clubs.php list all clubs from `tbleclubs` table and it looks like:

clubs.php

```
$database = new Database();
$res = $Db->query("SELECT * FROM tblclubs");
foreach ($res as $dataRow): ?>
    <span><?php echo $dataRow['id']; ?></span>
    <span><a hrer=""><?php echo $dataRow['name']; ?> </a></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and club.php listing all players in a club from `tblclub` table

club.php

```
$database = new Database();
$res = $Db->query("SELECT * FROM tblpclub");
foreach ($res as $dataRow): ?>
    <span><?php echo $dataRow['id']; ?></span>
    <span><a hrer=""><?php echo $dataRow['name']; ?> </a></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and finally the `player.php` is from `tbleplayer`:

player.php

```
$database = new Database();
$res = $Db->query("SELECT * FROM tblplayers");
foreach ($res as $dataRow): ?>
    <span><?php echo $dataRow['id']; ?></span>
    <span><a hrer=""><?php echo $dataRow['name']; ?> </a></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have set up a Foreign Key(FK) for tblclub as `clubs_id` and for tblplayers as `club_id`.

Now, my question is, how can I dynamically navigate to each selected item in next page like:

clubs->club->player

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are now rendering static lists.

To make the navigation dynamic you would basically need 3 things:

- create links with ids
- fetch this id from the URL
- and query the db using the WHERE statement to select that specific id

You have already started with links: `<a hrer="">`, but it's `href`.

**clubs.php** - would render the overview of all clubs with links to each club

Place this in your foreach to construct the links by attaching the ids.

```
foreach ($res as $dataRow) {
    $id = $dataRow['id'];
    $name = $dataRow['name'];
    $link = 'club.php?id=' . $id;

    echo '<span>' . $id . '</span>';
    echo '<span><a href="' . $link . '">' . $name. '</a></span>';
}
```

Now you can click for instance `club.php?id=2`.
But `club.php` would need to handle the incoming `id`, right?

**club.php** - renders the list of players with links to each player

You basically repeat the pattern from above, but with a different anchor base, this time it's `player.php`. You should get a list with `player.php?id=x` links.

How to handle the `id` in each of the scripts?

The `id` is incoming via `$_GET`.

You can use `var_dump($_GET['id'])` to see the value. Use a variable, like so `$id = $_GET['id']`.

(Later, when everything works: do not forget to secure and escape the incoming data properly.)

Then use `$id` in your database query:

`SELECT * FROM tblplayers WHERE player_id = ' . $id;`

Comment: Thanks Jens, this is perfect! Can you please also let me know how I can do this is a simple MVC way? Once again thanks

Comment: Glad i could help. I need some sleep 5am. I will post a mvc example when i respawn :)

Comment: Before i write a book on MVC explaining and repeating all the things. I just point you to a video tutorial which addresses MVC and application design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ It consists of 9 parts and should get you started really fast. The code for the example is over here: https://github.com/alexgarrett/simple-mvc

Comment: Thanks Jens , I already watched this tutorial but it was too confusing since there where lots of advanced pattern like bootstrapping an app, what I need is just having a simple MVC  to see how each of M, V, C take care of a simple project like this, once again thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have some errors in your HTML (it should `href` and not `hrer` for links)

Secondly, using a `select *` type of query is bad form;  you should generally be choosing specific keys from your table, and not just all of them.    You will also need to be link your tables if you want this to work properly;  it's difficult to tell what specific rows you have in your tables;  some structure would be helpful.

That said you would need to structure your queries something like this.  For example to get a list of players a specific club:

```
SELECT p.playerid, p.name,
FROM tblplayers p, tblclub c
WHERE p.club_id = c.club_id
```

this query will get a list of all players on a specific club.

As for linking you would could modify your links to be something like this.  To link to a specific player in a specific club, this would be the link on club.php to player.php:

```
<a href="player.php?<?php echo $dataRow['playerid']; ?>"><?php echo $dataRow['name']; ?></a>
```

Then to get the info you could just get the playerid from the URL by using a GET variable, like this: `$playerid = $_GET['playerid']`

and then get your information from the query, to do what you like.   You can use the data in any way you like from there.

This is just a start, but you should be able to extrapolate from this for the rest of your questions.   Hope this helps.